# How to remove uncommon elements from two arraylist

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, arraylist

How do I remove uncommon elements from `ArrayList`? The scenario is I have two `ArrayList` objects: `arr1` and `arr2`. `arr2` contains almost all elements of `arr1`. Now I want to remove such elements from `arr1`, which are not in `arr2`.

How can i achieve this? Is there any method or any technique to remove uncommon elements between two `ArrayList` objects?

Comment: Are the two lists sorted? Are there duplicate elements in the lists?

Comment: Yes both list are sorted...!

Answer (score 4):

Use `CollectionUtils.retainAll` : Returns a collection containing all the elements in collection1 that are also in collection2.

```
ArrayList commonList = CollectionUtils.retainAll(list1,list2);
```

then remove the elements of uncommon with for loop

Answer (score 3):

You can use `retainAll` method implemented in ArrayList.
It is like a set intersection.

Answer (score 1):

What about `arr1.retainAll(arr2);`?

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

```
arr1.retainAll(arr2)
```

Method 2:

```
    List<String> arr1;
    List<String> arr2 ;

    for(String s: arr2){
        if(arr1.contains(s))
            arr1.remove(s);
    }
```

I personally feel that 1 is better being more expressive and performance efficient.  If arr1 is not equal to arr2, JDK uses `System.arraycopy()` to copy complete `arr2` to `arr1` rather than removing individual elements. System.arraycopy is implemented natively and is very fast.

Following is reference to JDK code doing this.

```
    private boolean batchRemove(Collection<?> c, boolean complement) {
    final Object[] elementData = this.elementData;
    int r = 0, w = 0;
    boolean modified = false;
    try {
        for (; r < size; r++)
            if (c.contains(elementData[r]) == complement)
                elementData[w++] = elementData[r];
    } finally {
        // Preserve behavioral compatibility with AbstractCollection,
        // even if c.contains() throws.
        if (r != size) {
            System.arraycopy(elementData, r,
                             elementData, w,
                             size - r);
            w += size - r;
        }
        if (w != size) {
            for (int i = w; i < size; i++)
                elementData[i] = null;
            modCount += size - w;
            size = w;
            modified = true;
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

If only very few elements would be different, then method 2 would have been better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on some of the previous answers

```
/**
 * Returns elements in List A that are not in List B. (i.e. the relative complement of A with respect to B)
 * see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @return
 */
private <E> List<E> relativeComplement(List<E> a, List<E> b) {
    return ListUtils.removeAll(a, ListUtils.retainAll(a,b));
}
```